# Passing multiple values from one page to another

Tags: java, html, apache, jsp, tomcat

I have the followin question, how will I pass multiple values from one jsp page to another? I have i piece of code here, which works fine, but it only sends one value from one page to another (year):

```
<form method="post" action="Display data.jsp" name="inputpage" >
<select name="year">
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>
```

For example if I had another value, for example

```
String str = "value";
```

Is it possible to send it using form post method as well? I googled it, and the answer I found included loops and too much code, is there short and simple way of doing it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send as many variable you want  by Form Method.

For sending the value of String `Str`, assign its value to hidden field as:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden1" value=<c:out value="${variableName}" />
```

where variableName=str.

Comment: Nice. Also, please upvote and tick the answer that helped you as that will help the future visitors at stack-overflow community. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you submit the form all values of the form will be passed, they only need to be inside the form. You can read other values normally by using:

```
 request.getParameter(ParamName)
```

Take a look at [this article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a hidden input inside your form to pass other data using the form post?

```
<input type='hidden' id='myExtraData' value='hello' />
```